# Enable LDAP in Jenkins error

Tags: jenkins, ldap

```
Caused by: com.thoughtworks.xstream.converters.ConversionException:  : entity reference names can not     start with character '(' (position: START_TAG seen ...<userSearch>&(... @14:19)  :  : entity reference   names can not start with character '(' (position: START_TAG seen ...<userSearch>&(... @14:19)
```

---- Debugging information ----
    message             :  : entity reference names can not start with character '(' (position: START_TAG     seen ...&(... @14:19) 
cause-exception     : com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.StreamException
    cause-message       :  : entity reference names can not start with character '(' (position: START_TAG seen ...&(... @14:19)

Below is my config.xml.

```
<securityRealm class="hudson.security.LDAPSecurityRealm" plugin="ldap@1.1">
<server>ldap://office.adroot.bmogc.net:3268</server>
<rootDN>DC=office,DC=adroot,DC=bmogc,DC=net</rootDN>
<inhibitInferRootDN>false</inhibitInferRootDN>
<userSearchBase>DC=office,DC=adroot,DC=bmogc,DC=net</userSearchBase>
<userSearch>&(objectCategory=Person)(memberof=CN=ccusers,OU=UNIX Security Groups,OU=CTD_CM_RMG,OU=Corporate Clients V2,DC=office,DC=adroot,DC=bmogc,DC=net)/userSearch>
<groupSearchBase>DC=office,DC=adroot,DC=bmogc,DC=net</groupSearchBase>
<managerDN>ldapuser</managerDN>
<managerPassword>MUJ</managerPassword>
</securityRealm>
```

Answer (score 3):

Symbol < is missing in /userSearch>

Answer (score 0):

That search filter is invalid. LDAP-Compliant servers and APIs must reject that filter. Surround the filter with ( and ).